# Topological field isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: gn.general-topology, fields

Let $K$ be a topological field. If $K$ is a connected Hausdorff space, and is algebraically closed, is it true that $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ ?

(I have deleted my question on MathStackExchange)

Comment: Apparently Dieudonné has constructed proper dense subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ which are connected and algebraically isomorphic to  $\mathbb{C}$. I don't know if this answers the question since the meaning of "isomorphic" is unclear. See chapter X of Wieslaw's book. In the same chapter there is this result of Bergman and Waterman (Theorem 7): "Every discrete field can be embedded in an arcwise connected topological field". But of course algebraic closedness is not mentioned.

Comment: This answers the question. Sorry, I was not clear. By "isomorphic", I mean algebraically and topologically isomorphic.

Comment: Side remark: Even without connectedness assumption: every locally compact topological field that is algebraically closed is isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}$ as topological field.